# jQuery.BlackAndWhite.js erratic on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been redesigning my WP portfolio website of late and have been playing with a neat little aesthetic jQuery plugin, [BlackAndWhite](http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/canvas-experiments/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/demo.html), Which turns all of the images in my gallery view black and white and makes them recolor on hover using the HTML5 canvas.

I noticed one bug with the plugin is that if it runs before the images have finished loading, it will sometimes only grey-scale half of an image. So I have been using another tiny plugin to only run the script after I'm certain that the images have finished loading. see [waitforimages.js](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages)

The initialization script is the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.bwWrapper').waitForImages(function(){  
        jQuery(this).BlackAndWhite({
            hoverEffect : true // default true
        });
    });
});
```

where bwWrapper is the wrapper  around each img.

Now this works really nicely on most computers and browsers that I have tested thus far. Everything works the way it should. However, when I opened the site on my android, I noticed that only 50% of the images recolored. When I refresh the page, again only 50% go black and white, though it is different ones each time. Making the site fully responsive to mobile is still on my to-do list, but I have noticed this fairly blatant, yet difficult to explain bug.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you determined that the `waitForImages()` is selecting each image ? Try adding a border in the finished callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to preload the images because the plug in aleady do it. Try to download the last version of the script on github https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/jQuery.BlackAndWhite and if you still have problems send me a private mail with a link so I can check what could be the problem.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to this, I had not noticed the reply, but the new version seems to have done the trick, thanks!